# Why do you upvote a story identifications question?

Tags: discussion

The favorable response to a story identification question regarding an unfortunately [obscure sci-fi novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/66115/23892) I asked surprised me.

There are 3 reasons I can think of to upvote a story identification question.

1. The story description sounds familiar but you can't remember the title either. (Possible, but I think it's too obscure for more 20% of question viewers to remember it, especially since nobody's even taken a guess at what it might be. But this is why I would do it.).
2. The description sounds interesting to you and you'd like to try it out for yourself. (Most likely I think, since in comments it's compared to Sphere).
3. While not personally applicable to you, you find the question to be
   a good fit for the site. (Seems unlikely but possible).

Are there other reasons? Why do you upvote a story identification question?